# Different background color in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, background-color

I have problem with background color in Firefox see [a-build.ru/common](http://a-build.ru/common/) (left menu)

```
.leftmenu li ul li a {    
     background-color: #46494c;    
}
```

[1]: http://a-build.ru/common/ and here hkar.ru/gHS7 something here wrong...

Comment: I am failing to see the problem. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I am seeing the left menu in your site. what should I do next?

Comment: I checked in chrome. It looks the same in Firefox too. What is the issue?

Comment: It is not `.leftmenu li ul li a {` it is `.leftmenu ul li a {`

Comment: in chrome and in ie its the same color as background image, but in mozilla different

Comment: For me it looks the same in all 3 browsers (IE, firefox and chrome). Have you tried to Force Refresh the page in Firefox (ctrl + R)?

Comment: http://hkar.ru/gHS7 look it different

Comment: There's no such difference between my browsers (IE 9, Firefox 21, Chrome 27).

Comment: I have IE 8.0.6001 Firefox 21.0 Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m

Comment: thank you all =) i just changed it to transparent

Answer (score 0):

Seems some trouble with each version of browsers... Just changed it on transparent
thank you